# calculate max length of each field in csv file

Tags: r, csv

I have a groovy script that iterates through a csv and stores the maximum length of each field in the file:

```
def csv = new File('./myfile.csv').text

def max = [ ] as ArrayList

csv.eachLine { line, count ->

    def params = line.split(',')

    // skip the header line
    if (count > 0) 
    {
        params.eachWithIndex() { p, index ->        
            if (p.length() > max[index] ) {
                max[index] = p.length()
            }
        }
     }
}
println "Max length of fields: ${max}"
```

I would like to achieve the same goal using R, ideally using a library function.

How can I print out the max length of fields in csv file?

Example input:

```
foo,bar
abcd,12345
def,234567
```

Output:

```
Max length of fields: [4, 6]
```

Comment: Maybe something like `sapply(df, function(x) max(nchar(as.character(x))))` (if `df` is your input data)

Comment: Oh, and btw, you know nothing, Chris Snow ;P

Comment: Interesting comment David Arenburg :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in the data into a data frame and sapply the indicated function across its columns.  If the data is in a file replace `text = Lines` with `file = "myfile.csv"`.  See `?read.csv` for additional arguments which may or may not be needed depending on what your real file looks like.

```
# test data
Lines <- "foo,bar
abcd,12345
def,234567"

DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, colClasses = "character")
sapply(DF, function(x) max(nchar(x)))
```

giving:

```
foo bar 
  4   6
```

**Note:** One potential gotcha is if you have input like this.  Fortunately, this answer gets it correct:

```
Lines <- "foo,bar
abcd,1234567e9
def,234567"
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience the fastest way is to use the `fread` function from the `data.table` to read the file, then it's the same than Grothendieck answer

```
file_path <- './myfile.csv'
dt <- fread(file_path, colClasses = "character")
sapply(dt, function(x) max(nchar(x)))
```

Comment: This should be a comment, at max.